# Error: Parameter is not valid, when convert byte to image

Tags: c#, .net

I have a image field in sqlserver.

When insert row to Database i convert myimage to byte whith this code.

```
 Image img = Image.FromFile("D:\\Test.PNG");
 ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
 enter.Pic = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
```

When i want read this record, i convert byte to image with this cod e:

```
  ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
  Image img = (Image)ic.ConvertFrom(enter.Pic);
```

but when  convert byte to image, i get error

**Parameter is not valid**

Answer (score 2):

To convert the image to a byte array you could directly use the [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) method:

```
enter.Pic = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Test.PNG");
```

And to convert a byte array back to an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) instance:

```
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(enter.Pic))
using (Image image = Image.FromStream(stream))
{
    // use the image here
}
```